# Relationship between Windows 7.1 SDK and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi

Does installing the Windows SDK alter an existing installation of Visual Studio 2010?

After installing Windows 7 SDK, for each VS 2010 solution/project I have to change the value for Platform Tools from **v100** to **Windows7.1SDK**.  Otherwise I get build errors relating to the file *Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets*.  Did I miss something during the Windows SDK installation that would have correctly configured the two installations?

What exactly is the relationship b/w these two toolsets?  I know they are not mutually exclusive but I do not understand how they interact.

Comment: Did you install Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1? If so what is your install order?

Comment: Sheng Jiang: I did not install the update.  I do not think it fixes my problem.  I also read that this update breaks other things in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ceased to be a problem after moving to a new machine and re-installing VS 2010.